# TypeScript doesn’t recognize .d.ts from node module

Tags: typescript

I’m using [`babel-plugin-react-intl-auto`](https://github.com/akameco/babel-plugin-react-intl-auto) and TypeScript.

This package has defined typings in [*lib/types.d.ts*](https://github.com/akameco/babel-plugin-react-intl-auto/blob/v1.7.0/src/types.d.ts) (It is in lib when installed using npm). These override typings of another package.

```js
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl'

declare module 'react-intl' {
  interface ExtractableMessage {
    [key: string]: string
  }

  export function defineMessages<T extends ExtractableMessage>(
    messages: T
  ): { [K in keyof T]: FormattedMessage.MessageDescriptor }
}
```

They have specified this in [*package.json*](https://github.com/akameco/babel-plugin-react-intl-auto/blob/v1.7.0/package.json#L5)

```
{
  // ...
  "types": "lib/types.d.ts",
  // ...
}
```

This all seems fine. However, When I use this package, TypeScript complains about the function signature of `defineMessages`.

If I copy those typings into my own *index.d.ts*, it just works as expected.

For completness sake, this is my *tsconfig.json*:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"]
  }
}
```

Why won’t TypeScript use these typings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because TypeScript has no context as to which version of `defineMessages` to use.
TypeScript supports [merging declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) which also gets applied when importing modules.

Importing `babel-plugin-react-intl-auto` alongside `react-intl` should merge these definitions, allowing TypeScript to understand both syntaxes.